# Finding orthonormal basis using orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am very confused how to go about finding an orthonormal basis using a orthogonal basis. My book says to just normalize the vectors but it doesnt further explain. When i look at answers for transforming an orthogonal basis to an orthodonal basis, i see each orthogonal vectors scaled by some crazy fraction with what is usually a squared root in the denominator. There has to be SOME trick to do this besides guessing. I just cant believe that i'm suppose to be able to guess what scalar for each orthogonal vector gives an orthodonal basis. For example what if a vector is R^10!?

Comment: If $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is an orthogonal basis, then $$\frac{v_1}{\sqrt{\langle v_1;v_1\rangle}},\ldots,\frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\langle v_n;v_n\rangle}}$$ is an othonormal basis. "To normalize a vector" means "to divide it by its norm".

Comment: I think "orthodonal" ought to be "orthonormal" here.

Comment: Have you learned how to scale a vector down into a unit vector?

Answer (score 2):

The key is, as the book says, to normalize each of the vectors.  That is, we want to replace each vector with a multiple of that vector which has length one.  In other words, we want the unit vector in the same "direction".

The length of a vector $\vec x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is given by
$$
\|\vec x\| = \|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}
$$
The vector
$$
\frac{\vec x}{\|\vec x\|} = 
\left( 
\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}}
,\dots, 
\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}}
\right)
$$
will always have a length of $1$.  That is, $\left\|\frac{\vec x}{\|\vec x\|} \right\| = 1$.

So, we can simply replace each vector $\vec v$ with $\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}$ to go from an orthogonal basis (of non-zero vectors) to an orthonormal basis.