# Orthogonal to Orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, change-of-basis

I am having trouble completing the last step of my problem below:

Let $V= \beta [0,2] = \{ $All continuous function $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}$. Let $W = span(1,x,x^2) \subset V$. Find orthonormal basis of W.

I defined the standard inner product to be $<f,g> = \int_{0}^{2} f(x)g(x) dx$. Let $w_1=1,w_2=x,w_3=x^2$. Then I used the graham-schmidt formula to determine the orthogonal basis, and I get the following:

$$v_1=1,v_2=x-1,v_3=x^2-2x+\frac{2}{3}$$
(I would appreciate it if someone could confirm that this is a valid orthogonal basis because I am not 100% sure that I applied graham-schmidt properly).

Now my question is how should I convert the following orthogonal basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ into an orthonormal basis? I am not sure how to complete this final step because $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are not exactly vectors that I could just normalize. Thank you very much and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's actually Gram, not Graham.

Comment: But they _are_ vectors! They’re just not the tuples of scalars that you’re used to manipulating.

Comment: To expound upon @amd statement: The polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ behaves exactly the same and carries the same information as $(a,b,c)$ when adding and scaling—just like it $ai+bj+ck$.

Answer (score 1):

If you normalise the orthogonal basis, you will get an orthonormal basis. See also here: [Finding orthonormal basis using orthogonal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252684/finding-orthonormal-basis-using-orthogonal-basis).

Recall that, given any vector $x \neq 0$, its normalisation is:
$$ \frac{x}{\| x \|} $$
Moreover, recall that the norm induced by an inner product is:
$$ \| x \| := \, \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle}  $$